# Python Selenium .send_keys() only sending first character of my string

Tags: python, string, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I was trying to automate a post to Facebook using Python Selenium, and it was 90% complete. The only issue is that the string I give is "test," but when Facebook posts, it just sends the first character of "test," which is "t."

This is the code:

```
#libraries

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.webdriver.common.keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from time import sleep
import pyautogui


#fetching hashtags

def hashtags(hash_idea):
    url = 'http://best-hashtags.com/hashtag/' + hash_idea

    try:
        req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'})
        page = urlopen(req, timeout=10)
        page_html = page.read()
        page.close()
        page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')
        result = page_soup.find('div',{'class':'tag-box tag-box-v3 margin-bottom-40'})
        tags = result.decode()
        start_index = tags.find('#')
        end_index = tags.find('</p1>')
        tags = tags[start_index:end_index]

        return tags
    except:
        print('Something went wrong While Fetching hashtags')


def login(username, password):

    try:
        url = 'https://facebook.com'
        driver.get(url)
        user = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'email')))
        user.send_keys(username)
        pas = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'pass')))
        pas.send_keys(password)
        login_btn = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME,'login')))
        login_btn.click()

    except:
        print('Something went wrong while login process')

def upload(img_path,caption):
    try:
        btn1 = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]')))
        btn1.click()

        btn2= WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/span/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/i')))
        btn2.click()

        btn3 = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/i')))
        btn3.click()

        pyautogui.write(img_path)
        pyautogui.press('enter')

        cap = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]')))
        cap.send_keys(caption)

        sleep(5) # this is mandatory while doing some thing with bot

        btn_post = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div')))
        btn_post.click()
    except:
        print('Something Went Wrong While posting the image or video')

if __name__== "__main__":
    #turn for credentials, driver, and caption
    username = input('username : ')
    password = input('pass : ')
    img_path = 'pic1.jpg'
    hash_idea = 'covid'
    caption = 'test'  # if you want to
    caption = caption + '\n' + hashtags(hash_idea)
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:/Users/Asus/Downloads/Compressed/geckodriver-v0.32.0-win64/geckodriver.exe")
    login(username,password)
    upload(img_path,caption)
```

I wanted to automate the post with the text I provided in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try several alternatives

1. In the definition of `cap` replace `presence_of_element_located` with `element_to_be_clickable`.
2. Do what in 1. and moreover add

   ```
   cap = ...
   cap.clear()
   cap.click()
   cap.send_keys(caption)
   ```
3. Do what in 1. and moreover use ActionChains

   ```
   from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
   actions = ActionChains(driver)
   cap = ...
   actions.move_to_element(cap) # move the mouse to the middle of element
   actions.click()
   actions.send_keys(caption).perform()
   ```

If none works, then you can always send one character at a time

```
[cap.send_keys(c) for c in caption]
```

Comment: Hello, friend Thank you for your response; much appreciated. Although the problem has been fixed and the entire string can be sent, the post button is no longer functional. The previous issue, where a string couldn't send completely, has been resolved. The post button was functioning properly at the time but now the string can be send and the post button is not working 

Comment: @Raveen If the question is solved you may consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking ✔ on the left. Regarding the problem with post button, I suggest you asking a new question

Comment: Had the same issue with facebook. The last variant works fine.. I am sending leter 1 by 1